# Getting 'pred_table' information for predicted values of a model in 'statsmodels'

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, confusion-matrix

In the Python package `statsmodels`, `LogitResults.pred_table` can be conveniently used to get a "confusion matrix", for arbitrary an arbitrary threshold `t`, for a `Logit` model of the form

```
mod_fit = sm.Logit.from_formula('Y ~ a + b + c', train).fit() 
...
mod_fit.pred_table(t) 
#Conceptually: pred_table(t, predicted=mod_fit.predict(train), observed=train.Y)
```

Is there a way to get the equivalent information for test data? For example, if I

```
pred = mod_fit.predict(test)
```

how do I get the equivalent of

```
mod_fit.pred_table(t, predicted=pred, observed=test.Y)
```

Is there a way to get `statsmodels` to do this (e.g. a way to build construct a `LogitResults` instance from `pred` and `train.Y`), or does it need to be done "by hand" — and if so how>

Comment: not directly an answer: this shows similar calculations for the ROC curve (based on cross validation) http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/umich.box.com/shared/static/aouhn2mci77opm3v89vc.ipynb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a good idea and easy to add. Can you post a [github issue](http://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues) about it? You can do this with the  following code

```
import numpy as np
pred = np.array(mod_fit.predict(test) > threshold, dtype=float)
table = np.histogram2d(test.Y, pred, bins=2)[0]
```

Comment: Did this get implemented in the API?

Comment: Up? :) I don't think it's been implemented

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using `bincount`:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

def confusionmatrix( true, predicted, classnames="0 1", verbose=1 ):
    """ true aka y, observed class ids: ints [0 .. nclass) or bools
        predicted aka yhat: ints or bools, e.g. (probs > threshold)
    -> e.g.
        confusion matrix, true down, predicted across:
        [[0 2]  -- true 0, pred 0 1
         [7 1]  -- true 1, pred 0 1
    """
    true = np.asarray( true, dtype=int )
    pred = np.asarray( predicted, dtype=int )
    ntrue, npred = true.max() + 1, pred.max() + 1
    counts = np.bincount( npred * true + pred, minlength = ntrue * npred )  # 00 01 10 11
    confus = counts.reshape(( ntrue, npred ))
    if verbose:
        print "true counts %s:      %s" % (classnames, np.bincount(true))
        print "predicted counts %s: %s" % (classnames, np.bincount(pred))
        print "confusion matrix, true down, predicted across:\n", confus
    return confus

#...............................................................................
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 10
    np.random.seed( 7 )
    y = np.random.randint( 0, 2, n )
    p = np.random.randint( 0, 2, n )
    print "true:", y
    print "pred:", p
    confusionmatrix( y, p )
```